# My WCF data service client fails without throwing any error

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework-5

I'm building a WCF data service client/server application.

I don't know why, on the client, an request error, an entity validation error or another error in relation with the data service, the application doesn't throw any error and stops suddenly even if I put the method in a try-catch clause.

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe supply some code and your service configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For more information about your errors enable tracing in your server application: [Configuring Tracing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025(v=vs.110).aspx)

Basically you have to add to your `web.config` the following

```xml
<configuration>
   <system.diagnostics>
      <sources>
            <source name="System.ServiceModel" 
                    switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
                    propagateActivity="true">
            <listeners>
               <add name="traceListener" 
                   type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" 
                   initializeData= "c:\log\Traces.svclog" />
            </listeners>
         </source>
      </sources>
   </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

And open your trace file with trace viewer.

Comment: How can i use trace viewer.

Comment: On the other hand I want intercept error in my application to signal users that any error have been. How can do that?

Comment: You can double click on your trace file to open trace viewer or find it in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\vx.y\Bin. Usage is very intuitive, just can browse events and errors with details if any.

Comment: For communicating the errors to the users your try-catch blocks should be enough. In the trace viewer you can also see blocking errors like wrong endpoint config, wrong data contract. For the users that's irrelevant. It's info for the developer, no need to pass it to user.

Comment: I see I will try it. Thank you very muchfor your help.